# Start Year and End Year not displayed correctly from database in Yii2 update form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I am using jQuery (jui) date picker extension in Yii 2 form. I have a table in the database which stores the StartYear and EndYear. StartYear and EndYear are having varchar datatype.

For example: StartYear : June 2023 and EndYear : April 2024

I have configured the datepicker to show only months and year. Data is correctly getting saved in create action. But in the update action, incorrect values are getting displayed in StartYear and EndYear fields.

Below is the _form.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\jui\DatePicker;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Academicyear */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
        display: none;
    }
</style>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.picker').datepicker({
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     dateFormat: 'MM yy',

         onClose: function() {
        var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
     },



});
});
</script>
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin()?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5">
 <?php
if($model->isNewRecord)
{
    echo $form->field($model, 'StartYear')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                                            //'language' => 'ru',

                                            'options' => ['class' => 'form-control picker','readOnly'=>'readOnly'],
                                            'clientOptions'=>['changeMonth'=>true,
                                            'changeYear'=>true,
                                            'dateFormat' => 'MM yy',
                                            'readOnly'=>true]

]);
}
?>
<?php
// When model is opened in update action
if(!$model->isNewRecord)
{
$a=explode(' ',$model->StartYear);
$month=$a[0];
$year=$a[1];
 echo $form->field($model, 'StartYear')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                                            //'language' => 'ru',

                                            'options' => ['class' => 'form-control picker','readOnly'=>'readOnly'],
                                            'clientOptions'=>['changeMonth'=>true,
                                            'changeYear'=>true,
                                            'dateFormat' => 'MM yy',
                                             'onClose'=>' function() {

        $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date("<?php echo $year;?>", "<?php echo $month;?>", 1));
     }',]

]);
}
?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5">
<?php
if($model->isNewRecord)
{
    echo $form->field($model, 'EndYear')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                                            //'language' => 'ru',
                                            'options' => ['class' => 'form-control picker','readOnly'=>'readOnly'],
                                            'clientOptions'=>['changeMonth'=>true,
                                            'changeYear'=>true,
                                            'dateFormat' => 'MM yy',
                                            'readOnly'=>true]
]);
}
?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5">
<?php
// When model is opened in update action
if(!$model->isNewRecord)
{
    echo $form->field($model, 'EndYear')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
                                            //'language' => 'ru',
                                            'options' => ['class' => 'form-control picker','readOnly'=>'readOnly'],
                                            'clientOptions'=>['changeMonth'=>true,
                                            'changeYear'=>true,
                                            'dateFormat' => 'MM yy',
                                            'readOnly'=>true]
]);
}
?>
</div>
</div>
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?= $form->field($model, 'StartYear')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-control picker'],
    'clientOptions' => [
        'changeMonth' => true,
        'changeYear' => true,
        'dateFormat' => 'MM yy',
        'onClose' => 'function(dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            var fullDate = new Date(year, month, 1).toLocaleDateString();

            $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate("MM yy", new Date(year, month, 1)));
            $("#hidden-start-date").val(fullDate);
        }',
    ],
]) ?>

<input type="hidden" id="hidden-start-date" name="Academicyear[StartYear]" value="<?= date('m/d/Y', strtotime($model->StartYear)) ?>" />
```

Comment: If I used the above code, still on the update form incorrect value is getting displayed. Also  the format of the month and year on the form control should be for example June 2023. The code you gave displays the selected date as for example 4/1/2023

Comment: When the user selects Start year as June 2023 and End Year as May 2024 then the data is saved in the database table. Now when the user wants to update this record and opens the update form, the value fetched should be June 2023 and May 2024 on StartYear and EndYear, but 2023202320232023-06-151151 is displayed in StartYear and 2024202420242024-05-121121 is displayed in EndYear.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I changed the code as above, but the month and year which is selected from the drop down is not getting set into the control